# How to use namespaces between files?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.6

I'm using TypeScript 1.6.2 and atom-typescript. Trying to use a namespace on separate files:

```
// Main.ts
import * as _ from 'lodash'
namespace Test
{
  export var value = true
}

// Another.ts
namespace Another
{
  function Testing()
  {
    return Test.value == true
  }
}
```

I tried using references, but still didn't work, also have a valid tsconfig.json and it's setup to resolve the inclusion of definitions and files:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": true
},
"compileOnSave": false,
"filesGlob": [
    "./**/*.ts",
    "./Scripts/typings/**/*.d.ts",
    "!./node_modules/**/*.ts"
],
"files": [
    "./Scripts/typings/tsd.d.ts"
]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have `import * as _ from 'lodash', that makes the file *a module* on its own. https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

If you are using modules ... don't use namespaces as its just an needless point of indirection. Each file's variables (including namespaces) are distinct from other files.

Comment: Thanks Basarat!! But couldn't i take advantage of namespaces to not need relative paths? like `import { something } from '../../../../Service.ts'` I thought i could use namespaces to have the compiler resolve the file locations...

Comment: Sadly no. Its not supported at the moment. Its a burden left on other *build tools like webpack* or *runtime like nodejs*

Comment: So best option would be to wait for 1.8 and [Use path mappings in module resolution](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039)

Comment: Yes. But even then you might potentially need e.g. `foo/bar/baz/Service.ts` ... lets wait for the spec to settle :)